# Cascading overloaded cout operator error `No match` when used with other overloaded operators

Tags: c++, g++

I have overloaded `<<` in my code as a friend function. Even after using braces while cascading there is still the error

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = 
std::char_traits<char>]((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"complex conjugate is ")) 
<< c.myComplex::operator~()’
```

I have a class `myComplex`

```
class myComplex
{
    private:
    float real;
    float imaginary;    

    public:
    myComplex();
    myComplex(float a,float b);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& iso,myComplex& a);
    myComplex operator~() const;
};
```

The overload for `<<`, `~`and the constructors are as follows,

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oso,myComplex& a)
{
    oso<<a.real<<" + "<<a.imaginary<<"i"<<std::endl;
return oso;
}

myComplex myComplex::operator~() const
{
    return myComplex(this->real,-1*this->imaginary);
}

myComplex::myComplex(float a,float b)
{
    real = a;
    imaginary = b;
}
```

I use it in main as follows,

```
Line 1:    std::cout << "c is " << c << "\n";
Line 2:    std::cout << "a is " << a << "\n";
```

<strike>`Line 3:    ((std::cout <<"complex conjugate is ")<<(~c))<<"\n";`</strike>

```
Line 3:    std::cout <<"complex conjugate is "<<~c<<"\n";
```

Line 1 and 2 work fine, but  Line 3 gives the error. If it can cascade for Line 1 and 2 and since `~c` also returns an `ostream` why does it give an error for that?

Comment: Why all the parentheses? Those makes no sense.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, I was just trying out. Now, I know it because of `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `operator~()` returns by value, you are feeding a temporary object into your `ostream& operator<<` here:

```
std::cout <<"complex conjugate is "<< ~c <<"\n";
//                                    ^^ HERE! Temporary myComplex value.
```

The operator takes its 2nd argument by non-const reference `myComplex&`. A non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary. Change it to

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oso, const myComplex& a);
```

Answer (score 3):

A temporary object (in this case that returned by `operator~()`) cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference. Change argument of `operator<<()` to be a `const` reference:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& iso,myComplex const& a);
```

Comment: Thats a different way of notation, wasnt aware of that. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Use `const myComplex &` instead of `myComplex &`:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& iso, const myComplex& a);
                                                   ^^^^^
```

And change the implementation, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator <<` takes the second parameter by non-const reference, which means it can't bind to a temporary (such as the one returned by `~`). Change `operator <<` to accept `const myComplex&` as the second argument.

It would certainly be weird if the stream-output operator modified its argument anyway.

BTW, do you know that C++ has a built-in class `std::complex`?

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am aware of `std::complex` . I was trying an exercise from `C++ Primer Plus` that had this overloading question.